# Rails 5.2 ActiveRecord Query: Difference Between .joins and .include

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm learning Rails 5.2 (and MySQL really) for this new project, and I'd like to get more of an understanding about the differences between `join` and `includes`.

Say the project has a `Like` model:

```
<Like emoji_type user_id>
```

Here's the `User` model:

```
<User id username banned>
```

Let's say I want to look up ONLY likes from users that aren't banned (`status != 0`), and group them by `emoji_type`.

Here's the older query that DOESN'T filter banned users, and it  uses `includes`:

```
@likes_map = likes.where.not(emoji_type: nil)
  .includes(:user)
  .group_by(&:emoji_type)
```

This is the query I have so far (which works), and it uses `joins`:

```
@likes_map = likes.joins(:user).select(:emoji_type, :username, :status)
  .where("emoji_type IS NOT NULL")
  .where("status != 0")
  .group_by(&:emoji_type)
```

I've noticed some differences in the kind of result that `includes` returns vs. `joins` when I try logging things to the console:

```
# includes
p @likes.username => nil
p @likes.user.name => username

# joins
p @likes.username => username
p @likes.user.name => nil

# with both joins and includes,
# this just returns a Like record, 
# with no info from User:
p @likes
```

- Why is the object returned by the two queries different?
- Why can't I see any userinfo from a `joins` query when I log to the console?
- I know that `includes` does some eager-loading. Is my `joins` query above inefficient in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `joins` is an actual SQL joint allowing you to query nested model. Available data of a join are all data of both joined tables.

```rb
Like.joins(:user).where(user: { email: "your@email.com"})
```

If there is multiple times the same name (timestamp for example with `created_at`/`updated_at`) you can access each using the table before with a where clause like that `joins(:user).where('users.created_at < ?', Time.zone.now)`

- `includes` is used to eagerload nested data to avoid `n+1` query. It does **not** join with another table (that's why `likes.username` returns `nil` (it should actually raise an error unless you've delegate attributes on the model I guess).

```rb
Like.includes(:user).map do |l|
  l.user.email
end
```

You can use both in the same time if necessary

```rb
Like.joins(:user).includes(:user).where(user: { email: "your@email.com"}).map do |l|
  l.user.id
end

# just for example because there is an easier way to do it of course
# Like.joins(:user).where(user: { email: "your@email.com"}).pluck('users.id')
```

I would say this should answer all your 3 questions.